# scala add a string in the mapper

Tags: string, scala, dictionary, functional-programming

Hi I have the following code that gets each column and produces a string separated by commas.

```
val selectCols    = t.columns.map( c => cmap.getOrElse(c.name, c.name)).mkString(",")

Output: store_id,date_id,user_id,data,other_column
```

But I would like to modify this map function to get the following string:

```
t.store_id,t.date_id,t.user_id,t.data,t.other_column
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is the difference between these two outputs? The fact that `t` is prepended to them?

Comment: What is `cmap`?

Comment: what is `t` ? whar is `columns` ?

Comment: The difference between the two is plainly obvious. The author is generating a SQL fragment and wants the column names prefixed by the alias "t.", in order to create a query such as "SELECT t.one, u.two FROM table1 as t, table2 as u WHERE...". It's also obvious how to help him/her without knowing what "cmap" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val selectCols    = t.columns.map( c => cmap.getOrElse(c.name, c.name))
.map(c => s"t.$c")
.mkString(",")
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.
Thank you,